# Оптимизация генератора комбинаций c#

Tags: c#, комбинаторика

Мне нужно получить все возможные сочетания символов из массива определенной длины, немного погуглив (дабы не изобретать велосипед) нашел такой код :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] arAlphabet = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','A','B' }; // используемый алфавит
    int n = 20; // количество мест в комбинации
    char[] arBuffer = new char[n];
    const string fileName = "ResultGenerate.txt";
    // файл при каждом запуске должен создаваться заново
    StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(fileName);
    writer.Close();
    // Накопитель строк.
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder((int)Math.Pow(arAlphabet.Length, n) * (n + 2));

    RecursionGenerateCombinationsToFile(arAlphabet, arBuffer, 0, stringBuilder);
    // Записываем полученный результат в файл.
    writer = File.AppendText(fileName);
    writer.Write(stringBuilder.ToString());
    writer.Close();
}

private static void RecursionGenerateCombinationsToFile(char[] arAlphabet, char[] arBuffer, int order,
                                                        StringBuilder stringBuilder)
{
    if (order < arBuffer.Length)
        for (int i = 0; i < arAlphabet.Length; i++)
        {
            arBuffer[order] = arAlphabet[i];
            RecursionGenerateCombinationsToFile(arAlphabet, arBuffer, order + 1, stringBuilder);
        }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arBuffer.Length; i++)
            stringBuilder.Append(arBuffer[i]);
        stringBuilder.AppendLine();
    }
}
```

Работает, вроде бы, хорошо, но нужно оптимизировать, что бы не потреблял столько памяти (жрет более 4гб оперативы), но при этом был максимально быстрым ?

можно вместо промежуточного `stringBuilder` записывать сразу в файл, тогда память почти не жрет, но очень медленно работает. Мб у вас будут еще какие идеи решения данной проблемы ?

---

С использованием временного `stringBuilder`

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] arAlphabet = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };     // используемый алфавит
            int n = 20;      // количество мест в комбинации
            char[] arBuffer = new char[n];
            string fileName = "ResultGenerate.txt";

            StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(fileName);    // файл при каждом запуске должен создаваться заново
            writer.Close();

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder((int)Math.Pow(arAlphabet.Length, n) * (n + 2));
            RecursionGenerateCombinationsToFile(arAlphabet, arBuffer, 0, fileName, stringBuilder);
        }

        // Рекурсивный медод
        static int count = 0;
        static int allcount = 0;
        static void RecursionGenerateCombinationsToFile(char[] arAlphabet, char[] arBuffer, int order, string fileName, StringBuilder stringBuilder)
        {
            if (order < arBuffer.Length)
                for (int i = 0; i < arAlphabet.Length; i++)
                {
                    arBuffer[order] = arAlphabet[i];
                    RecursionGenerateCombinationsToFile(arAlphabet, arBuffer, order + 1, fileName, stringBuilder);
                }
            else
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < arBuffer.Length; i++)
                    stringBuilder.Append(arBuffer[i]);
                        stringBuilder.AppendLine();
                count++;

                if (count > 500000)
                {

                    StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText($"ResultGenerate{allcount}.txt" );
                    writer.Write(stringBuilder.ToString());
                    writer.Close();
                    count = 0;
                    stringBuilder.Clear();
                    allcount++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Писать в файл с буфером.

Comment: @tym32167 будет ли вот так оптимально [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/fDrVDXtV) ? сделал временный буффер, а так же по 500к записываю в каждый файл, что бы при чтении все было норм

Comment: Вставляйте весь код в вопрос. У меня такая ссылка в принципе не откроется.

Comment: @tym32167 вставил

Comment: Зачем вам вообще StringBuilder, если вы пишете все равно все в файл?

Comment: @tym32167 чтоб быстрее было. Если писать сразу в файл по комбинации, то это занимает много времени, но мало ресурсов, а если чисто в стрингбилдер, то мало времени, но много ресурсов, вот я и решил сделать нечто среднее. Да и разве не это вы имели в виду, говоря "буффер" ?

Comment: Нет, не это. Вам обязательно нужно в разные файлы писать? Или можно и в один все записать?

Comment: @tym32167 в разные, чтоб читать легче было. Буду рад, если поможете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переписал немного ваш пример. Заменил StringBuilder на StreamWriter, сделал запись с буфером. Запись ведется в 1 файл (для записи в несколько файлом можете легко сами переделать код). Памяти это будет есть примерно 10 мегабайт - размер буфера.

```
void Main()
{
    char[] arAlphabet = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };     // используемый алфавит
    int n = 20;      // количество мест в комбинации
    char[] arBuffer = new char[n];  

    string fileName = @"ResultGenerate.txt";
    if (File.Exists(fileName)) File.Delete(fileName);

    // Будем писать в файл с буфером в 10 мегабайт. При этом никакой string builder не нужен
    // Каждые 10 мегабайт буфер будет сливаться в файл. Если будет медлено работать, увеличте размер буфера. 
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(File.OpenWrite(fileName), 10 * 1024 * 1024)))
    {       
        RecursionGenerateCombinationsToFile(arAlphabet, arBuffer, 0, fileName, sw);
    }
}

static void RecursionGenerateCombinationsToFile(char[] arAlphabet, char[] arBuffer, int order, string fileName, StreamWriter writer)
{
    if (order < arBuffer.Length)
        for (int i = 0; i < arAlphabet.Length; i++)
        {
            arBuffer[order] = arAlphabet[i];
            RecursionGenerateCombinationsToFile(arAlphabet, arBuffer, order + 1, fileName, writer);
        }
    else
    {
        writer.Write(arBuffer);
        writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);      
    }
}
```

**UPD** Чтобы писать в несколько файлов.

Добавим нехитрый класс

```
public class MuliWriter : IDisposable
{
    private StreamWriter _writer;

    public StreamWriter CurrentWriter
    {
        get { return _writer; }
    }

    public void SwitchOutput(string fileName)
    {
        _writer?.Dispose();             
        _writer =  new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(File.OpenWrite(fileName), 10 * 1024 * 1024));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {       
        _writer?.Dispose();     
    }
}
```

Перепишем чуть чуть код

```
void Main()
{
    char[] arAlphabet = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };     // используемый алфавит
    int n = 20;      // количество мест в комбинации
    char[] arBuffer = new char[n];  

    string fileName = @"ResultGenerate.txt";
    if (File.Exists(fileName)) File.Delete(fileName);

    // Будем писать в файл с буфером в 10 мегабайт. При этом никакой string builder не нужен
    // Каждые 10 мегабайт буфер будет сливаться в файл. Если будет медлено работать, увеличте размер буфера. 
    using (var sw = new MuliWriter())
    {       
        sw.SwitchOutput(fileName);
        RecursionGenerateCombinationsToFile(arAlphabet, arBuffer, 0, fileName, sw);
    }
}

private static int count = 0;
private static int files = 0;

static void RecursionGenerateCombinationsToFile(char[] arAlphabet, char[] arBuffer, int order, string fileName, MuliWriter writer)
{
    if (order < arBuffer.Length)
        for (int i = 0; i < arAlphabet.Length; i++)
        {
            arBuffer[order] = arAlphabet[i];
            RecursionGenerateCombinationsToFile(arAlphabet, arBuffer, order + 1, fileName, writer);
        }
    else
    {
        writer.CurrentWriter.Write(arBuffer);
        writer.CurrentWriter.Write(Environment.NewLine);

        count++;
        if (count > 10000000)
        {
            writer.SwitchOutput($"ResultGenerate{++files}.txt");
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, действительно тратит мало ресурсов и быстро работает, но ток я пока не понимаю ,как тут можно сделать запись меняя файлы. Не прошу писать код за меня, лишь идею подсказать

Comment: Тут много вариантов, как это сделать. Как самый простой - написать класс, сделать StreamWriter полем класса. Отправлять этот класс как параметр функции. Когда надо будет сменить поток - просто текущий писатель в поток завершаете, новый создаете, пишете новый в то поле, где был старый.

Comment: не совсем понятно, создаю я класс, создаю поле `StreamWriter _writter;` , получается, в класс надо запихнуть еще и `using (var sw = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(File.OpenWrite(fileName), 10 * 1024 * 1024))) ` и посылать туда название файла, а как же `RecursionGenerateCombinationsToFile `..... чет я совсем запутался (( Я немног наглею, но можно пример ? или идею по легче

Comment: @Lolidze Добавил простенький писатель с переключением файлов

Comment: спасибо большое, ща буду разбираться

Comment: можете объяснить конструкцию `_writer?.Dispose();`, а именно, что значит знак вопроса ? тип идет проверка на налл или что ?

Comment: @Lolidze Это эквивалентно `if (_writer!=null) _writer.Dispose();`